# Console.log function property difference between object literal vs. dot notation

Tags: javascript, node.js, console.log

I create objects using two different notations and then console.log them:

```
object = {key: 'value', func: function() {}};
console.log(object);
```

output: { key: 'value', func: [Function: func] }

```
object.key = 'value';
object.func = function() {};
console.log(object);
```

output: { key: 'value', func: [Function] }

Why there's a difference in the outputs? Does it matter?

Comment: dot notation have more syntax limitations

Comment: Is this node.js or a browser console? Unable to reproduce in chrome

Comment: I used Node.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with dot notation and bracket notation.

In example (a) you are declaring a property name (`func`) and value (a function) in an object literal. In example (b) you are assigning a function to a property afterwards.

In the first case, `func` is used as a *Binding Identifier* which is used to give the function a name.

That isn't the case in the second example.

This isn't likely to make much difference, but function names can be useful when debugging. You can give a function expression a name explicitly:

```
object.func = function func () {};
```

Comment: Ok, but I think it would make sense, even if there were no function name associated in the first case either, then.